# testEquals(), testHashCode() and testToString() 

Tags: java, junit

I prepared short Java class. Could anyone show me how write voids:
testEquals,
testHashCode,
testToString for this code in junit? I have a little problem with it;)

```
public class JW {
    private String name;
    private int quantityVoters;
    private int voted;

    public JW( String nam, int quantityV ) {
        if( nam == null || nam.length() == 0 || quantityV < 10 )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "JW: Wrong" );
        name= nam;
        quantityVoters= quantityV;
        voted= 0;
     }

    public void voting( int n ) {
        if( n < 0 || n > quantityVoters - voted )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "JW: soething wrong with voting!" );
        else
           voted += n;
    }

    public int novote() {
        return quantityVoters - voted;
    }

    public boolean equals( Object o ) {
        return o != null && o instanceof JW && ((JW)o).name.equals( name );
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "JW " + name + ": quantity Voters: " + quantityVoters + ", voted: " + voted;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `.equals()` method is already wrong -- and so is your `.hashcode()`. What's your point exactly?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @fge: what is wrong with them? They seem to be consistent with eachother.

Comment: fge - maybe that's why he/she wants to test them.

Comment: @Thilo `.equals()` will return true if `o instanceof JW`, which means there exist `o`, `o1` so that `o.equals(o1)` but `o.hashCode != o1.hashCode` --> this breaks the equals()/hashcode() contract

Comment: @fge: It will only return true if the name also matches. In that case, the hashCode will also be the same (because it is the name's hashCode)

Comment: @fge: Yes, && shortcuts, but only for **false** clauses, not true ones. If `o` is not an instance of `JW` it will shortcut and not check the name, but that is correct behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Small example to get you started:

```
public class JWTest extends TestCase {

  public void testEquals(){
      JW one = new JW("one", 10);
      JW two = new JW("two", 10);
      assertFalse("nullsafe", one.equals(null));
      assertFalse("wrong class", one.equals(1234));
      assertEquals("identity", one, one);
      assertEquals("same name", one, new JW("one", 25));
      assertFalse("different name", one.equals(two));
  }
}
```

With regards to `equals` and `hashCode`, they have to follow a certain contract.
In a nutshell: If instances are equal, they must return the same hashCode (but the opposite is not necessarily true). You may want to write assertions for that as well, for example by overloading assertEquals to also assert that the hashCode is equal if the objects are equal:

```
 private static void assertEquals(String name, JW one, JW two){
     assertEquals(name, (Object)one, (Object)two);
     assertEquals(name + "(hashcode)", one.hashCode(), two.hashCode());
 }
```

There is no special contract for `toString`, just make sure that it never throws exceptions, or takes a long time.

Comment: +1 for clarity.  -1 for asserting different things in the same test method.  Especially for hashCode - it should have its own test cases, not piggyback on the test cases for equals.

Comment: @DavidWallace -1 to you for being anal. Asserting multiple things in one test case is fine. It stems method bloat and some outcomes require multiple assertions. Get over it.

Comment: Bohemian - it's possible to express your disagreement, without the name-calling.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Of course, hashCode should have its own test method. I did not want to imply that it should not. However, whenever you assertEquals, you could/should also assert the hashcode as well. I almost think this should be built in to JUnit's assertEquals (since the contract for equals and hashCode are linked).

Comment: Thilo - OK, my apologies.  It looked to me like you were trying to wrap the two up into one test case.  I'm not sure that I agree that you should always assert equality of hashcode whenever you do assertEquals; because assertEquals is used in a lot of different contexts.  For example, in my version of the test for toString, I don't think there's much point in making assertions about the hashcode of the String that's returned from toString - that would be outside of the scope of the test.  But it's an interesting idea and worth discussing.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using those names for your tests.  Each test case should assert JUST ONE thing about the behaviour of your class.  So, you might have test cases called -

- equalsReturnsTrueForJWWithSameName()
- equalsReturnsFalseForJWWithDifferentName()
- equalsReturnsTrueForSameObject()
- equalsReturnsFalseForObjectThatIsntJW()
- hashCodeReturnsSameValueForJWObjectsWithSameName()
- toStringReturnsStringWithNameAndNumberOfVotersAndNumberVoted()

So, for example, the first and last methods here might look like this.

```
@Test
public void equalsReturnsTrueForJWWithSameName(){
   JW toTest = new JW( "Fred", 5 );
   JW other = new JW( "Fred", 10 );
   assertTrue( toTest.equals( other ));
}

@Test
public void toStringReturnsStringWithNameAndNumberOfVotersAndNumberVoted(){
   JW toTest = new JW( "Fred", 5 );
   toTest.voting( 2 );
   String expected = "JW Fred: quantity Voters: 5, voted: 2";
   assertEquals( expected, toTest.toString());
}
```

The other methods will follow a similar pattern.  Try to make sure that each test only has one assertion in it.  Feel free to post again if you get stuck; I don't mind providing more help.

Comment: +1 for sticking with principles of TDD, but -1 for being a bit too pedantic with TDD principles. When the tests cases are this trivial it's fine to group them together. There's always a balance between concise code (as in @Thilo's answer) and the "right" way to do it, as in your answer.