# JUnit: Create multiple testmethods against one method?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Can we create multiple test methods in JUnit against single method? I have explored this in eclipse and I could not find any way. If we can than kindly tell me a way.

Comment: Just type some code and dont use the wizzards for every single bit of brain usage

Comment: You mean that there is one method under test and multiple JUnit test methods testing that method? Sure, why not? Why do you need an Eclipse feature for that?

Comment: thanx guys i got it now, i was just confused :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, JUnit can do this just fine.  Write as many test methods as you need.  Give each of them a name that describes what requirement it's testing, and which case, and annotate each of them with `@Test`.

Check out my answer to [testEquals(), testHashCode() and testToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675302/testequals-testhashcode-and-testtostring/8675398#8675398)  for an example of what test methods you might have in a simple case.  Ignore the other answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CodePro](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=codepro&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/&ei=9EZHT-u9FIvprQfw4qCqDw&usg=AFQjCNGUsuLjlQLG3OmBdVQS1e-v92Sezw&sig2=5GyhUgWGbmUK-Y0cK1rDtQ) .
This will generate multiple test cases for a single method.
This can be installed in eclipse.

You can add this [link](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/3.6) to install CodePro in Eclipse.
Go to help and then into S/W updates.
Then paste this link on add site.