# how to find missing jUnit testcases from java project

Tags: java, junit

I am using Junit4 and java 1.6

In my project I have more than 500 classes and test cases for each classes. But when I look in to individual class (Ex. Person.java and methods are findById, findBySSN, findByName) and the respective test case (Ex. PersonTest.java), many test cases are missing for most of the methods (TC available for findById only and no TC for findBySSN, findByName).

1. Is there any way to find missing test cases for classes.
2. And in most of the test cases I can see as assertTrue(true) and not even asserts for some cases. Is there any way to find missing assert missing test cases.

Awaiting for your response. Thank you

Comment: Are you asking for a coverage tool that will tell you which of your methods are not being called by your tests?

Comment: Hi David, from code coverage perspective I am using Emma and yes we can get information from Emma report also. But I want to know the missing test cases from class without executing testcases. Is it possible to get this info? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the missing test cases"?

Comment: Person.java
 findById
 findBySSN
 findByName

PersonTest.java
 testFindById


here testFindBySSN and testFindByName is missing in PersonTest

Comment: Oh, dear!  That's how people wrote tests in about 2003.  Don't write one test method per application method.  Write one test method per behaviour that needs to be tested.  And beginning your test method names with the prefix "test" is kind of an anti-pattern, because it encourages you to think in terms of the outdated "test a method" instead of "test a behaviour" mode of testing.  Read my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8675302/1081110 for more detail on how this works.  Ignore the other answer to that question.

Comment: It can't be stressed enough that you should listen to David's advice. Also worth noting that implementing unit tests after the code has been written is a dangerous game. Perhaps you should concentrate on a slightly higher level of testing that will test the api. Automated tests are super important but excessive and/or poorly written unit tests can be just as damaging to the codebase as not having any, arguably more so.