# How do you add PowerMock to your project?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I am using mockito in my project and then found i could not use mockito for static classes and so have been told to download and use powermock. 
i download from here https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/Downloads, this file specifically. PowerMock 1.6.0 with Mockito and JUnit including dependencies

Do i just need to import the JARs from this into my project library? or is there more to it?

Comment: Why do you want to mock static classes?

Comment: @DavidWallace manager wants every line of code to be covered/tested. what is wrong with testing static classes?

Comment: I didn't ask why you'd want to test static classes.  Obviously, you want to test them.  I asked why you'd want to _mock_ them.  Mocking a static class doesn't seem to be a particularly useful thing to do, unless your code is very poorly designed.

Comment: @DavidWallace ok. what's wrong with mocking them?

Comment: Needing to do it is a symptom of either badly designed application code, or badly scoped tests.  In most cases, you should find that you never feel a need to mock a static method.  The reason why I asked the question was to find out whether you thought there was a need to do it, or whether this was a purely academic question.  If you can post a case where you think you need to mock a static method, I will make a suggestion about what you could do differently - either changing the design of your application code, or changing the scope of your tests.

Comment: @DavidWallace in that case, I direct you to another question I asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605211/how-do-you-test-if-statements-with-junit/27605291?noredirect=1#comment43633778_27605291

this requires me mocking a static class using powermock

Comment: Well, firstly, chiastic-security has given you an excellent answer to that question already.  Secondly, I don't see anything static in that question.  How does it relate to what you're asking here?

Comment: @DavidWallace look, all I want is a place to go to learn how to unit test and I was hoping here. maybe the questions haven't been great but I have searched the internet high and wide and all the tutorials I can find only focus on assertEquals and assertTrue. i just need a guide to follow so I can unit test if statements, for loops and know precisely when to use 'verify' and 'when'. Remember I'm new to TDD as well so I need a very basic tutorial that focuses on the above

Comment: OK, well lesson one is - don't try to mock static classes.  In fact, I would recommend staying away from PowerMock completely - it encourages very bad habits.  I'll try to find a question that I answered a couple of years ago that deals with some of the basics for you.

Comment: Go have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8675302/) - there are two opposing points of view there in the answers, but you should be able to work through what's going on.

Comment: @DavidWallace thanks. and I am trying to mock the class string utils which is from org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils, but you're saying this is a big no no?

Comment: Don't mock `StringUtils`.  Whatever you're doing with `StringUtils`, treat it as part of the behaviour under test.  So when you test your own method, test its entire behaviour, including the part that's delivered by `StringUtils`.

Comment: @DavidWallace okay, i guess I say thanks for the help. not sure how much that question will help me.

Comment: @DavidWallace I think you seriously exaggerate in your claim that mocking static methods "is a symptom of either badly designed application code, or badly scoped tests". Of course in *some* cases it will be, but not always. I give you one example from a real-world project (one in which I favor *integration* tests over *unit* tests, trying to keep mocking at a minimum). It uses the JasperReports library for PDFs. The static method `JasperFillManager.getInstance` is the entry point used in client code. I mocked it in order to write tests to simulate exceptions thrown by Jasper's `fill` method.

Comment: @DavidWallace Another case for mocking statics is the `FacesContext` abstract class from JSF, which has a `static getCurrentInstance()` method, commonly used in Java EE apps. I mocked it so that I could verify calls to the `addMessage` method, used for posting messages to the UI. As far as I know, there is no other way to do it, and `FacesContext#addMessage` is the standard way to post error/info messages from the server to the UI in a Java EE 7 app.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't use maven. You just have to add the corresponding powermock version.
Take a look to this mapping and choose the right version:

```
Mockito             PowerMock
1.10+               1.6.0
1.9.5-rc1 - 1.9.5   1.5.0 - 1.5.6
1.9.0-rc1 & 1.9.0   1.4.10 - 1.4.12
1.8.5               1.3.9 - 1.4.9
1.8.4               1.3.7 & 1.3.8
1.8.3               1.3.6
1.8.1 & 1.8.2       1.3.5
1.8                 1.3
1.7                 1.2.5
```

Comment: i do use maven. i understand this is a very simple question. more a question of imports. im using mockito 1.9.5 but just downloaded powermock 1.6...
my download folder contained 6 jar files and i was wondering to i just 'add existing jars' to library and if so, which ones?

Comment: if you are usfin maven just add the dependency to your pom.xml. After that build your project and it should be fine. If that does not work you can rebuild eclipse project with mvn clean:eclipse eclipse:eclipse.