# how do you test if statements with junit?

Tags: java, junit

I can't seem to find any tutorials online that address this

I have this `if` statement:

```
if (basket.getCustomerId() != null) {
                Basket exBasket = findBasketByCustomerId(basket.getCustomerId());
                if (exBasket != null && exBasket.getBasketId() != null) {
                    return exBasket;
                }
```

and I want to write a unit test that will test each individual line to see if it is doing the right thing.

Any ideas?

```
@Test
    public void testBasketWithANullCustomerId(){
        basketInformationServiceImpl.createBasket(mockBasket);
        assertNotNull(mockBasket.getCustomerId());
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

The purpose of unit testing isn't to test *statements* but *methods*. The right thing to do is not to consider this line, but to consider the method that it appears in, and ask what you want that method to do: what sort of input does it take, and what sort of output should it produce?

Then write tests that take some *typical* inputs, and check that they give correct outputs, and also some *edge case* inputs (like `null`, 0, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, etc.) and check that you get the right outputs for those too.

If this is your entire method (which actually it can't be, but if it's the essence of it), I'd test:

- a `basket` with a `null` customer ID;
- a `null` basket (unless you're certain this can never happen), because currently this code will give a `NullPointerException`;
- a basket that has a customer ID that should allow you to find a known `exBasket`;
- a basket that has a customer ID that will return an `exBasket` of `null`;
- a basket that has a customer ID that will return an `exBasket` that isn't null, but whose basket ID is `null`.

Comment: okay makes sense. but how do you actually write a test to test if statements. i cant really figure out what the syntax would look like. 
i want some way to test if it is not null then return the rest of the if statement. not sure how to go about it. thanks

Comment: @BlueShark I think you're looking at it the wrong way. As I say, don't think about testing *statements* at all. Think about *inputs and outputs*.

Comment: ok look at my question for a updated answer to your first bullet point. is this correct?

Comment: @BlueShark quite possibly, although you will need `mockBasket` to be defined somehow... and I'm assuming that `.createBasket()` is the method that contains the statement you've mentioned?

Comment: this is at the top of my class. @Mock private Basket mockBasket;
sorry, which statement? .createBasket() is the method inside basketInformationServiceImpl class

Comment: and do you mind just talking me through say bullet point 5, a basket that has a customer id that will return an exBasket of null?
just so I can get the hang of this unit testing. thanks

Comment: I mean something where you end up with an `exBasket` that isn't `null`, but where `exBasket.getBasketId()` returns `null`.

Comment: so something like this. sorry for code in comments...@Test
 public void testBasketWithCustomerIdWillReturnAnExBasketOfNull(){
  when(mockBasket.getCustomerId()).thenReturn(null);
  basketInformationServiceImpl.createBasket(mockBasket);
 }

Comment: come on chiastic security, this is your time to step up and be counted!!

Comment: @chiastic-security How to test onMessage method when the output is void?   https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183874/onmessage-testing-method?noredirect=1#comment350088_183874

Comment: The purpose of unit testing is to reduce risk.  That means testing what you have to in order to accomplish that goal.  If you consistently focus on methods, you'll eventually get burned by not considering statements.

Answer (score 1):

To test in the way you seem to want to (emphasizing line coverage), you need a test for each situation you want to test (for example, one test for a null basketId, another for a not null basketId, another for another case you wish to test).

Mocking frameworks (such as [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito)) can be used to to set preconditions for a test.  For an example of one case you can say

```
@Test
public void myTestWithNonNullBasketId() {
    Basket inputBasket = Mockito.mock(Basket.class);
    when(inputBasket.getBasketId()).thenReturn(1); //Or whatever we want basketId to return, null if you want to check that case.
    ... //More mocking as needed, presumably to dictate whatever findBasketByCustomerId might return.

    //Call the method you are testing, use org.junit.Assert assertions to check outputs.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an excerpt from a method you're trying to test, it sounds like you need at least two test cases - one where `basket.getCustomerId()` is expected to be null and one where it isn't.  In both cases you should be able to test the method's return value (I'm assuming a `Basket` will be returned as well in the event `getCustomerId()` is null) against the expected outcome.