# How do I simulate multiple inputs from a JUnit test case into my program?

Tags: java, junit

I have written a program which looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Triangles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> triangleLengths = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {

            System.out.print("Triangle length #" + i + ": ");
            triangleLengths.add(i,user_input.next());   
        }

        if (triangleLengths.get(0) == triangleLengths.get(1) && triangleLengths.get(1) == triangleLengths.get(2)) {

            System.out.println("This triangle is an equilateral triangle");

        } else if (triangleLengths.get(0) == triangleLengths.get(1) || triangleLengths.get(0) == triangleLengths.get(2) || triangleLengths.get(1) == triangleLengths.get(2)) {

            System.out.println("This triangle is an isosceles triangle");

        } else if (triangleLengths.get(0) != triangleLengths.get(1) && triangleLengths.get(1) != triangleLengths.get(2)) {

            System.out.println("This triangle is a scalene triangle");

        } else {

            System.out.println("The input does not make a triangle!");

        }


    }
```

}

I have been tasked with writing a JUnit test case to essentially try and 'break' my program through testing with various inputs. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this as a total Java newbie - could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Not what you're asking, but your logic for figuring out when the input can't make a triangle is a little bit off.  Three lengths can't make a triangle if the longest length is greater than or equal to the sum of the other two, so there needs to be some arithmetic in there.

Answer (score 1):

So I made a suggestion on how to solve it.

you want to make it so that you can test with different parameters automatically without needing to enter it manually so i isolated the triangles part as seen below.

**EDIT:** I redid the code somewhat

The normal run class **src/main.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> triangleLengths = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print("Triangle length #" + i + ": ");
            triangleLengths.add(i, user_input.next());
        }

        // Result output will be here
        Triangle subject = new Triangle(triangleLengths);
        if (subject.getTriangleType() == Triangle.Type.INVALID) {
            System.out.println("Triangle is invalid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Triangle is: " + subject.getTriangleType());
        }
    }
}
```

The JUnit class **test/TrianglesTest.java**

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TrianglesTest {

    /**
     * Testing with String inputs (what you'd enter manually)
     */
    @Test
    public void testWithStrings() {
        List<String> triangleLengths = Arrays.asList("len1", "len2", "len3");

        Triangle subject = new Triangle(triangleLengths);
        // Example of checking if expected type
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.ISOSCELES, subject.getTriangleType());
    }

    /**
     * Testing with numbers as what I'd expect the triangle to be made of
     *
     * Here you test with a triangle object
     *
     * Haven't tested what the 3 types is sorry :O
     */
    @Test
    public void testWithNumbersAsObject() {
        Triangle subject = new Triangle(4, 5.32, 7);
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.SCALENE, subject);
    }

    /**
     * This piece you check the static method but have no object
     */
    @Test
    public void testWithNumbersStaticMethod() {
        assertEquals(Triangle.Type.ISOSCELES, Triangle.getTriangleType(3.4d, 4d, 1.111d));
    }
}
```

And lastly the actual code you wanted to test **src/Triangles.java**

```
import java.util.List;

/**
 * I created so you can both have an object of the triangle or make the check purely static
 * maybe you need an object type for later?
 */
public class Triangle {

    final double side0;
    final double side1;
    final double side2;

    public Triangle(List<String> triangleLengths) {
        this(Double.parseDouble(triangleLengths.get(0)),
                Double.parseDouble(triangleLengths.get(1)),
                Double.parseDouble(triangleLengths.get(2)));
    }

    public Triangle(double side0, double side1, double side2) {
        this.side0 = side0;
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
    }

    public Triangle.Type getTriangleType() {
        return Triangle.getTriangleType(side0, side1, side2);
    }

    public static Triangle.Type getTriangleType(double side0, double side1, double side2) {
        if (isEquilateral(side0, side1, side2)) {
            return Type.EQUILATERAL;
        } else if (isIsosceles(side0, side1, side2)) {
            return Type.ISOSCELES;
        } else if (isScalene(side0, side1, side2)) {
            return Type.SCALENE;
        } else {
            return Type.INVALID;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isScalene(double side0, double side1, double side2) {
        return side0 != side1 && side1 != side2;
    }

    private static boolean isIsosceles(double side0, double side1, double side2) {
        return side0 == side1 || side0 == side2 || side1 == side2;
    }

    private static boolean isEquilateral(double side0, double side1, double side2) {
        return side0 == side1 && side1 == side2;
    }

    public enum Type {
        EQUILATERAL,
        ISOSCELES,
        SCALENE,
        INVALID
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Note that I return the answer from the **Triangles** class instead of writing it out immidiately. And only in the manual run I write it out from the main method.

Comment: Nice answer: you give good explanations; and it is a viable solution. The only thing I would do different: there is no to be as lazy about formatting as he is. Meaning: empty lines for no reason are not helpful; so you could edit your answer to get rid of those for example. And for the record: as that method is already returning multiple times: then you dont need the **else** things at at all! Just go for a series of `if (something) { then return }` That saves quite a bit of "logic" and reading work.

Comment: Ah yea true, will do that a little later today :) just wanted to fast show him a how the general pattern for it would look using his example, was a bit fast refactoring of his code

Comment: Appreciate the response - sorry about sloppy coding habits, I am just learning. Just a quick one - where you've written methodNameHere - which method name are you referring to?

Comment: that is now the method called **public static Triangle.Type getTriangleType** but it is just the checking code for the triangle you wrote I put into a method to isolate the purpose a bit. I redid the code and you'd want to read that

Comment: great... not sure if you know of any comprehensive java tutorials? The one I did was quite frankly awful and I'm not sure what half of what you've written menas

Comment: Okay Jake I quickly found this link https://www.udemy.com/java-tutorial/ but there are thausand of java tutorials out there. A great starting place to look is at https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjava/ in the right side panel there are links to java tutorials. else google will help you too

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Wisienkas is right on spot; but I think a bit more of conceptual background would be helpful.

You see, when you start coding, "user input" from *stdin*, using a Scanner, that's like "the big thing". You fetch some value, do some processing on that; and print some results.

The problem is: that is not how "real world" works; and therefore you ran into that problem that your code wasn't testable. The key thing to understand here is: you need just a little bit of abstraction, in order to make things better.

Those are:

1. your "processing" code goes into its own classes and methods. And ideally, those methods except the data to work on as **argument** when invoked.
2. your "processing" code should return its results. When you just print to System.out it is almost impossible to verify what some code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing for you to do is to redesign your code, so that

- the triangle logic is in its own class,
- the user input logic is in its own method,
- the `main` method is absolutely minimal.

Then, you can unit test the triangle logic and the user input logic separately.  And if `main` is small enough, you can get away without writing a unit test for it.

However, that's *not* what you asked.  If you want to keep your code *exactly* as you've written it, you can test it by setting `System.in` and `System.out` to streams where you control the input and output.

Your test class might look something like this.  This redirects `System.in` to read from a `String` that you specify in each test, and `System.out` to write to a stream whose content you can verify afterwards.

```
public class TrianglesTest {
    @Test
    public void identifiesEquilateralTriangle() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = setStreams("5 5 5 ");
        Triangles.main(new String[0]);
        assertEquals("This triangle is an equilateral triangle", output.toString().trim());
    }

    // Plus a whole lot more tests for other cases

    private ByteArrayOutputStream setStreams(String input) {
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));
        ByteArrayOutputStream toReturn = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(toReturn));
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you suggest I go about making the triangle logic its own class and the user input its own method?

Comment: Look at Wisienkas' answer.  He's written a pretty good Triangle class - although it still has the same logic error that your original code has, which I pointed out in my comment under the question.

Comment: I have used wisienkas' code, and all I get is plenty of errors saying something like "Could not resolve Triangle to a type", and in my little experience of this, don't know what that means

Comment: OK, maybe you shouldn't have accepted Wisienkas' answer if you can't get it to work.  As a general rule, once the green tick appears, people assume that your problem is solved.  Having said that, have you put the Triangle class into a file called Triangle.java, and is it in the same directory as the other files in your project?

Comment: I have figured out all the errors 1 by 1 but the JUnit test case just fails when I run it

Comment: Yeah, the second test case in Wisienkas' answer is wrong. It asserts that a scalene triangle is isoceles. But the whole point of the test cases in that answer is to demonstrate how to write your own tests. You'll need far more than just two test cases anyway.

Comment: david-wallace as I mention It was an example of tests, it was not an example of that it was actually passing tests, I also wrote that I had no idea what those 3 kinds of triangles were. 

He asked how he could test it using Junit, so i showed isolation in method and objects and how junit tests looks....

Additionally please don't couple System.in with unit tests, it is considered bad practice when you already could have a fine interface setup.

Comment: Yes, @Wisienkas that's pretty much what my last comment says.  Your answer demonstrated how to write tests, and it did so very successfully.  It's a good answer.  The fact that one of your test cases contains an incorrect assertion is irrelevant to the quality of your answer, and I did not mean to make any kind of slight on your answer.  I'm sorry if you took it that way.  But I think that's why Jake is was unable to get the test case to pass - he maybe didn't look closely enough at what it was asserting.

Comment: @DavidWallace you are correct. he'll just have to get used to the language. Another source he could lookup would be Test Driven Development, but that should probably be once he is confortable in the language

Comment: @Wisienkas Your comment reminds me of one of the very first questions that I answered, and also commented on someone else's answer.  Jake might benefit from looking at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8675302 (but please ignore the person who called me a rude word in the comments).